# Child component sharing state with parent?

Tags: reactjs, components, extend

I'm pretty new to React and I'm struggling a bit with my first task.

I'm creating a generic TextBox (from MaterialUI) component and I've created a child component (NumberInput) that extends TextBox. The problem is that whenever I type any input into the NumberInput, the NumberInput state doesn't seem to be updated. Any tips would be appreciated!

Parent:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import { Validations } from './validations'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class TextBox extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: null,
            error: false,
            errorMsg: null
        };

    this.setValue = this.setValue.bind(this);
    this.setError = this.setError.bind(this);
    this.setErrorMsg = this.setErrorMsg.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.checkForErrors = this.checkForErrors.bind(this);

}

// Handles changes upon each edit of the textbox. Updates the state value and checks for errors.
handleChange(event) {
    this.setValue(event);
}

setValue(event) {
    var value = document.getElementById(this.props.id).value;
    this.setState({ value: value }, () => this.checkForErrors());
}

setError(error, errorMsg) {
    this.setState({ error: error });
    this.setErrorMsg(errorMsg);
}

setErrorMsg(errorMsg) { this.setState({ errorMsg: errorMsg }) }

getValue() { return this.state.value }

getError() { return this.state.error }

getErrorMsg() { return this.state.errorMsg }

// Checks for input error
checkForErrors() {
    var input = this.getValue();
    console.log(input);
    var validations = Validations(this.props, input);
    this.setError(validations.error, validations.errorMsg);
}

render() {
    let {
        label,
        placeholder,
        maxLength,
        minLength,
        maxNumber,
        minNumber,
        disabled,
        required,
        type,
        multiline,
        id,
        name,
        allowSpecialCharacters,
        allowWhitespace
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <br/>
            <TextField
                error = { this.getError() }
                label = { label }
                helperText = { this.getErrorMsg() }
                placeholder = { placeholder }
                inputProps = {{ maxLength: maxLength }}
                disabled = { disabled }
                required = { required }
                type = { type }
                multiline = { multiline }
                onChange = { this.handleChange }
                id = { id }
                name = { name }
            />
        </div>
    );
 }
};

TextBox.propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string,
    helperText: PropTypes.string,
    placeholder: PropTypes.string,
    maxLength: PropTypes.number,
    minLength: PropTypes.number,
    maxNumber: PropTypes.number,
    minNumber: PropTypes.number,
    disabled: PropTypes.bool,
    required: PropTypes.bool,
    type: PropTypes.oneOf(["button", "checkbox", "color", "date", "datetime-local", "email", "file",
    "hidden", "image", "month", "number", "password", "radio", "range", "reset", "search",
        "submit", "tel", "text", "time", "url", "week"]),
    multiline: PropTypes.bool,
    id: PropTypes.string,
    name: PropTypes.string,
    allowSpecialCharacters: PropTypes.bool,
    allowWhitespace: PropTypes.bool
}

TextBox.defaultProps = {
    label: '',
    helperText: '',
    placeholder: '',
    maxLength: 100000,
    minLength: 0,
    maxNumber: 100000,
    minNumber: -100000,
    disabled: false,
    required: false,
    type: 'text',
    multiline: false,
    id: 'input',
    name: '',
    allowSpecialCharacters: true,
    allowWhitespace: true   
}

export default TextBox;
```

Child:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TextBox from './textbox';
import { Validations } from './validations'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

// const NumberInput = props => {
//  return (
//      <TextBox {...props} type="number" />
//  )
// }

class NumberInput extends TextBox {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            value: null,
            error: false,
            errorMsg: null
        };  
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <TextBox
                    label = { "NumberInput" }
                    type = { "number" }             
                />
            </div>
        )

    }
};

export default NumberInput;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import TextBox from './widgets/textbox/textbox';
import TextArea from './widgets/textbox/textarea';
import NumberInput from './widgets/textbox/numberinput';

class App extends Component { 
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to 
  reload.
        </p>
        <TextBox type="text" label={"Textbox"} />
        <NumberInput label={"NumberInput"} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Updated `NumberInput`:

```
const NumberInput = props => {
    return (
        <TextBox {...props} type="number" id="inp" />
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a class here for your child component and extend it from the parent. This process is very simple when you pass your handler function to your child component.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "initial value",
  }

  handleChange = e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value });

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Change the value:</p>
        <Child onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.value} />
        <p>{JSON.stringify(this.state.value)}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Child = props => {
  return (
    <input onChange={props.onChange} value={props.value} />
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do in my `App.js` is call on a component `NumberInput`. `NumberInput` extends from another component called `TextBox`. Inside my `TextBox` component, I do all all my validations and return whether or not the input is valid. However, it keeps failing because the values being passed into the validation function is null. Am I going about this in the wrong manner? Should I be doing all my validations inside `NumberInput`? If I wanted to create another component, say `UrlInput`, will I have to redo all of the validations again inside `UrlInput`?

Comment: I can't quite follow your code but you don't need to extend a component from another one. This is not a React way I suppose. You can create reusable components (not extends from another one) and can use them in multiple places in multiple ways. But, if you keep another state in this component it will be hard to pass this state to your parent component. You are trying to create a simple form component here with error checks. Maybe it is better to examine present packages which exactly do this.

Comment: Thanks! I moved away from trying to extend the component and that helped resolve one of my problems. The updated `NumberInput` is above now :-)

Comment: If I want the prop `id` to have a unique value each time, should I define a separate function? I'm currently running into this problem where my defaultProps are setting `id: 'input'`

Comment: You are welcome. Do I understand right, you need a unique id? If so, you can use a `uiid` generator maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Solved my problem :-)